# Query Optimization - Potential ill effects of adding an full text index to a frequently updated table

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, amazon-rds

We have a query of the following type which we are trying to optimize.

```
SELECT table_one.*
FROM table_one
INNER JOIN table_two    
ON table_two.fk_id = table_one.id
WHERE (table_one.h_id = 20626 AND table_one.is_active = true)
AND (Match(table_two.search_field) against ('+some_term*' IN boolean mode))    
ORDER BY table_one.updated_date DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

As evident, table two has a **FULL TEXT SEARCH** index on **search_field**. We are planning to get rid of table_two by moving the search_field column to table_one. That would remove join from the query thereby improving the execution time.

However, table_one is frequently updated. How does FTS index respond to **frequent update**?

Our gut feeling is that the index should be affected as long as the search_field column itself is not updated. But a bit of experienced hindsight would be great.

To add to it, is there any way to improve the **ORDER BY clause**?
Any other suggestions/improvements would be appreciated.

Comment: *table_one is frequently updated. How does FTS index respond to frequent update?* If the field indexed with FT index do not alters during update query, the index is not altered.

Comment: @Akina Can you suggest any improvement in the query ?

Comment: How many updates per second are you talking about?